# Linq to Xml query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a xml structure like this:

```
<Items>
    <Configuration>
        <ConfigurationSetting>Setting1</ConfigurationSetting>
        <ConfigurationSetting>Setting2</ConfigurationSetting>
    </Configuration>
    <MetaData>
    ...
    </MetaData>
    <Group>
        <GroupType>MyType1</GroupType>
        <GroupType>MyType2</GroupType>
    </Group>
    <Group>  <--- Looking for this Element
        <Reference>MyReference1</Reference>
        <Reference>MyReference2</Reference>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <GroupType>MyType3</GroupType>
        <GroupType>MyType4</GroupType>
    </Group>
</Items>
```

I want to write a Linq query that returns the first **"Group"** Element that contains a Sub-Element **"Reference"**.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like:

```
        var grp = doc.Root.Elements("Group")
            .Where(g  => g.Elements("Reference").Any())
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or as xPath (perhaps in `XmlDocument`): `@"/Items/Group[Reference]"`

Comment: i did try everything but it didnt work.. coudn't believe that the solution is that easy ;-) thank you!